# Visual studio not highlighting suggestions while typing

Tags: c++, autocomplete, autosuggest

I use visual studio with C++. When typing a word, visual studio makes suggestions, as expected, but does not always highlight them. Here is what I mean:

I type "stri", and "string" gets highlighted, and this allows me to press enter and complete the word.

[image: Like this.]

Then, if I erase only part of the statement, it no longer highlights string,[image: like shown here.]

And finally, most importantly, if I want to use that string elsewhere, it does not highlight the name. 
[image: Example.]

In the example you can see that pressing enter goes to a new line instead of completing the word. Pressing tab would work, however it still doesn't highlight the word, which I don't like, and also I am used to pressing enter, so I would prefer not to press tab.

Comment: I think suggestion gets highlighted when you got to it using "member lookup", that is after explicitly typing namespace name or `this->`.

Comment: Hmm, well I'm not sure, but I do know that it works in all 3 cases on my brother's computer, we're in the same room so i can compare any behaviour...I have found a solution, but I'm not sure if it's a good one. I'll add an answer showing it for others.

Answer (score 6):

**Working solution:**

Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **C/C++** > **Advanced**. Then find **Member List Commit Aggressive**. Set this to true. 
Then optionally find **Member List Commit Characters** and remove all the characters except the colon character.

This solution is almost perfect and it will work for anyone who wants to do the same thing as me.